# How can I add tags at different HTML positions in Google Tag Manager?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, facebook-pixel

Currently, the GTM script is added within the `<head>` section on all the pages of our site. So, naturally, when I add tags to the GTM, they are all added to the `<head>` section.

However, it seems like for certain pixel conversion script snippets, they need to be added outside of the  section or within the  section.

For instance, I need to add `<script>fbq('track', 'Purchase');</script>` right after the  tag.

And for Google's conversion pixel, I need their snippet within the `<body>` section.

How can I control the placement of the tags in GTM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to control the placement of the tags in Google Tag Manager. It is possible to control the execution of the tag.

What I would suggest for Facebook Conversion pixels is use a custom HTML tag. Insert the code to your pixel there and wrap the pixel code in HTML tags.

For example:

```
<html>
<!-- Facebook Pixel Code -->
<script>
!function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s){if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;
n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window,
document,'script','https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
fbq('init', 'XxXXxXXXXXXXX'); // Insert your pixel ID here.
fbq('track', 'PageView');
</script>
<noscript><img height="1" width="1" style="display:none"
src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=XxXXxXXXXXXXX&ev=PageView&noscript=1"
/></noscript>
<!-- DO NOT MODIFY -->
<!-- End Facebook Pixel Code -->    
</html>
```

More instructions can be found here: [https://www.facebook.com/business/help/1021909254506499][1]

Then you can set the trigger to fire on pageview, DOM ready or window loaded. When the tag loads via GTM it doesn't mean it executes. By setting the